# What makes a project publishable in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, class-library

I'm unclear on what makes a project in visual studio "right click publishable", does anyone have an idea/information on this?

[image]

I realize that project types such as console apps, web apps, etc should be right click publishable.  However, I'm struggling with figuring out what makes a class library right click publishable.  I have several class libraries that I've created that don't have "publish" available as an option when right clicking the project file in visual studio, however I have happened across a class library project from another developer that has the option to right click publish.

What/where is the right click publish option configured on a project?

Comment: As far as I know, you can only publish Web Application and Web Site projects ...

Comment: @jrummell I was thinking similar, but I'm getting different behavior with this class library project.  Hence my question :D